# Middleware request user return Anonymous User when using DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I don't think there is another way round this part from editing DRF source code. I want to add a custom middleware to Django, but I'm using DRF TokenAuthentication and my middleware interceptor require that request.user is authenticated.

Please, is there a better way to do it apart from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The best way, I think of doing this is to create my own TokenAuthentication middleware and add to Django middlewares to intercept request and then use SessionAuthentication for DRF.

I check DRF source code and saw that request.user is only used in SessionAuthentication, since I already intercept request in my AuthenticationMiddleware, then SessionAuthentication is best way to authenticate DRF.